# Can I use the part of my regexp expression in the second part of text.replace function?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a text that contains 10km and I want to convert this to m:

```
var sample = "100km"
sample = sample.replace(/(\d)+(km)/g,(d * 1000).toString() + "m")
```

This doesn't work because I believe "d" is not recognized as the one from the regexp. Is there a way around this? (I want to use the "100" found in the text, and also, it might be occur more than once in the text, say "100m 10m" etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String#replace` with a callback and do you calculation:

```
sample = '123.456km';
sample = sample.replace(/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)k(?=m)/g, function($0, $1) { return parseFloat($1)*1000; } );
//=> 123456m
```

OR of you want to avoid lookahead:

```
sample = sample.replace(/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)km/g, function($0, $1) { return parseFloat($1)*1000+'m'; } );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for the most part, however, it doesn't work out on decimals, and I'm not sure why, for instance: 1.120km returns 1.120000m 
Is it because of parseInt?

Comment: Thanks, but this still gives the same result :S I still get 123.456000m for 123.456km 
I tried using parseFloat and that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do calculations in the replacement string. That said, in you case, you could simply add three `0`:

```
sample.replace(/(\d+)km/g, "$1000m")
```

`$1` means the first capturing group, i.e. `(\d+)`.

[Demo](http://www.regexr.com/38s0p)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. So I tried doing calculations in the repl. string, and it works. However, adding 3 zeros might not always work, as it could be a decimal